# Q. How to dynamically add queries to a table adapter in Visual Studio

Tags: sql, visual-studio, tableadapter

I have setup a Table Adapter in Visual Studio linked to a SQL Server db.
I've followed the MSDN tutorials and I have manually setup some queries for this TA. I think of these queries as "pre_hardcoded". I call these queries using the default code:

```
Me.ItemFactTableAdapter.My_Pre_Hardcoded_Query(Me.MasterDataSet.ItemFact)
```

I want to dynamically call data in different configuration (from the same Master Table) and thus I need a lot of these pre-hardcoded queries. So, instead of writing 1k queries I've want to use something like this:

```
    TableName = "ItemFact"
    H_Label = "ChainName"
    V_Label = "ItemName"
    Dim Measure As String = "Volume"

    Dim Select_Clause As String = "select distinct " & H_Label & "," & V_Label & ", Sum(" & Measure & ") as " & Measure & " "
    Dim From_Clause As String = "from " & TableName & " "
    Dim Where_Clause As String = ""
    Dim GroupBy_Clause As String = "group by " & H_Label & "," & V_Label

    Dim SelectionQuery = Select_Clause & From_Clause & Where_Clause & GroupBy_Clause
```

Where I can dynamically update the values of "Measure" and the "H" & "V Labels".
The question is: How do I declare this SelectionQuery to be a valid part of the TA so that I can use it like:

```
Me.ItemFactTableAdapter.SelectionQuery (Me.MasterDataSet.ItemFact)
```

Answer (score 1):

for dynamic query you need create generic DataAdapter:

```
 Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(SelectionQuery, Me.ItemFactTableAdapter.Connection)
 da.Fill(Me.MasterDataSet.ItemFact)
```

Comment: On inserting the code I receive this highlight on da:
`Overload resolution failed because no 'New' is accessible)`
And also:
`value of type 'MyApp.MasterDataSet.ItemFactDataTable' cannot be converted to System.Data.DataSet.`
My initial TA is defined by defaul on load as:    `Me.ItemFactTableAdapter = NewMyApp.MasterDataSetTableAdapters.ItemFactTableAdapter())`

I'm, using the VS 2012 Express.

Comment: Change DataAdapter to SqlDataAdapter.

Comment: I've changed it to SQLDataAdapter and the msg is gone, da is now defined correctly. I'll work through the code and check the dynamic query build. Will reply when over. 10x

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't found an answer  to my initial question ON HOW TO ADD QUERIES TO A TABLE ADAPTER, but based on @lomed answer I've done a workaround. Thus, instead of filling the TA on 1st load and then pulling data with different queries, I'm updating the whole dataset on each query. I believe this method may be more time-consuming when applied to big datasets, but for now it works.

```
Dim strConn As String = "Data Source=XXX;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True"
Dim conn As New SqlConnection(strConn)
Dim oCmd As New SqlCommand(SelectionQuery, conn)
Dim oData As New SqlDataAdapter(SelectionQuery, conn)
Dim ds As New DataSet
```

and then attach the dataset to objects like:

```
Chart1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Table1")
```

instead of:

```
Chart1.DataSource = Me.ItemFactBindingSource
```